# insert names on a dataframe read on a URL

Tags: pandas, dataframe, insert, names

i want insert this names list ['preg', 'plas', 'pres', 'skin', 'test', 'mass', 'pedi', 'age', 'class'] on my data frame export from this URL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv

I want creat a dataframe or list with names

Thks

Comment: Are you saying you want to make the columns the names list? If so. You need to read in the data at the url with read_csv() . Then you can set the columns attribute of the DataFrame = your_names_list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv',
            names = ['preg', 'plas', 'pres', 'skin', 'test', 'mass', 'pedi', 'age', 'class'])
```